# Pool query returns undefined using node-postgres

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm doing some query using `pg` (https://node-postgres.com/):

```
pool.query(someQuery, function (error, result) {
   // some actions
}
```

Every `result` should have a rows array (we can read about that here https://node-postgres.com/api/result)

So, we should have some array of rows:

`let arr = result.rows;`

And by `result.rows[rowNumber]` we should be able to get our rows from the database. But in my case `result.rows` is `undefined`.

I'm **sure** the `query` is **correct**.

Instead of `result.rows` I can get my row by `result[2].rows[0]` (and get values from table columns like `result[2].rows[0].id`, `result[2].rows[0].title` etc.). First two objects (`result[0]` and `result[1]`) are rubbish.

Could someone explain to me what is going on here? I always got my rows of db through `result.rows`as stated in the documentation of `pg`.

**upd.: query, error, result**
[image]

Comment: can you share output of `console.log(error, result)` also it would be better if you can share the query as well.

Comment: See updates above.

Comment: I can see 3 queries in your query : 1. `with t1 as ... , t2 as ... select * from t2;` 2. `with t1 as .... t2 as ... , t3 as ..., t4 as ... select * from t2, t4;` 3. `with t1 as ... , t2 as ... select * from t1, t2;` So result of this is array of results of those queries. Run only last query and you get expected result.

Comment: That helped me.